# Expanding arbitrary variable to a drive, path etc. in a DOS batch

Tags: batch-file, variable-expansion

I am using a dos batch which processes file using passed parameter:

```
process.bat "D:\PROJECT\TEST FILES\test.pdf" 72
```

*process.bat:*

```
gswin32c -r%2 -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile="%~n1-%%d.jpg" -- "%~1"
```

We can see that the parameter is expanded to the file name in the batch: `%~n1`.
However I was asked to rewrite the batch to read parameters from a text file:

*params.txt*

```
1 D:\PROJECT\TEST FILES\test.pdf
2 72
```

So I have modified the *process.bat*:

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%A in ('type ..\params.txt') do set P%%A=%%B
gswin32c -r%P1% -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile="%~nP2%-%%d.jpg" -- "%~1"
```

But %~nP2% doesn't work.

I have found that `for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%P1%) do %%~dA` could help me but it looks cumbersome.

So is there any other way to expand arbitrary variable to a name, drive, path etc.?

Comment: FWIW, I haven't looked back since I stopped writing batch files and started using JavaScript with cscript.exe.

Comment: Good suggestion. Will give it a try.

Comment: Glad that was helpful. Re using JavaScript: The scripts are a pain to run (`cscript /nologo myname.js`) but you can get around that. I do it by using the extension `jx` for my command scripts. To set this up, right-click such a file and tell Windows to open it with `c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe`. Then use regedit to change the "open" command for that type by going to HKCR\jx_auto_file\shell\open\command and changing the default key's value to `"c:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe" /e:JavaScript /nologo "%1"`. Happy coding. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, those only work with the special number-based arguments. But you can turn your variable into one by passing it to a subroutine in the batch file. Example:

```
@echo off
set P1=D:\PROJECT\TEST FILES\test.pdf
call :Split %P1%
echo %FNAME%
exit /b 0

:Split
set FNAME=%~n1
exit /b 0
```

...prints "TEST" (the name part of test.pdf)